# Find missing sequence gaps mysql

Tags: mysql, sequence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find missing value in sequence within groups in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727392/how-to-find-missing-value-in-sequence-within-groups-in-sql)

I have Column with values like

```
MAC00006300
MAC00006301
MAC00006302
MAC00006305
.....
LED00006002
...........
LED00006008
ALD18965
ALD18967
ALD18968
.......
ALD19000
```

I  need the missing in between values

```
MAC00006303,MAC00006304 
LET00006003 ..... LET00006007
ALD18969,ALD18970.....ALD18989

SELECT NAME, VALUE + 1
FROM testmissingexampledata  mo
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    testmissingexampledata mi 
        WHERE   mi.VALUE = mo.VALUE + 1
        )
ORDER BY
        VALUE;
```

When I executed the above query I was able to retrieve only next missing record. Can any one suggest to me how to retrieve all missing records?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the rows that are missing without a list of all possible numerical values to `LEFT JOIN` against.

This query (which feels like it could be better/stronger/faster, but it works) will find you the gaps:

```
set @last_prefix = null;
set @last_value = null;
select result from (
    select @last_prefix, @last_value, name,
      @prefix := substring(name,1,3) as prefix,
      @value := substring(name,4) as value,
      case when @prefix = @last_prefix and @value != @last_value +1
        then concat ("gap from ", @prefix, ": ", @last_value+1, " to ", @value-1)
        else "ok" end as result,
      @last_prefix := @prefix, @last_value := @value
      from t20120921
) foo
where result != "ok";
```